# How to get django form value in javascript without saving it into model

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

I created a django form and I need not to save those values in my database. But I don't know how to access those form values in javascript.

**balance.html**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dateinput').datepicker();
    var a = document.getElementsById("{{ form.start_date }}").val;
    alert(a);
});
</script>   

<div>
    <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %} Start Date: {{ form.start_date }}&nbsp;&nbsp; End Date:{{ form.end_date }}
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="See Results" id="tryonce">
    </form>
</div>
```

But I can't get the result.
How those form value can be retrieve in javascript ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The {{ form.start_date }} expands to:

```
<input id="id_start_date" type="something">
```

You can always right-click and inspect the element in most of the modern browsers.

So use:

```
var a = document.getElementsById("id_start_date").val;
```

I suggest you use the jQuery version:

```
var a = $("#id_start_date").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this also if you want to directly get values

```
var start_date="{{ form.data.start_date }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The form is rendered automatically as valid html. You can access form fields by their id using the prefix `id_field_name`. So `start_date` field has id `id_start_date`:

```
var a = document.getElementsById("id_start_date").val;
```

You should read documentation on form rendering [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template)